# Possible bug during close vote

Tags: bug, mathjax, user-interface

When I am voting on a close vote, the "duplicate" tab shows the potential duplicate as suggested by others.  However the MathJax in the duplicate tab does not render for me, but it does render in the original tab.  Switching back and forth between the two tabs, and/or waiting, does not resolve the issue.

I'm running Chrome 26.0.1410.64 on Windows 7.

Comment: This bug has been noted in past. See for example: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6216/latex-not-rendering-with-exact-duplicate-in-review

Comment: @Thomas: I believe that the SE team reads questions tagged [tag:bug]. If not, we will contact them.

Comment: @robjohn Perhaps it's time? I was hit once again by this issue for [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/434365/43351), inadvertently closing as duplicate because the TeX agreed with the original question for long enough to trigger my extrapolation algorithm.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: as you've probably noticed, the closing system has undergone a big change. Is this problem still an issue?

Comment: @robjohn Yes, I still experience it every time.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: I'm checking to see if the devs have had a look at this.